# Why aren't there even more zombies?

Tags: izombie-2015

In iZombie, it is discovered that zombieism is transfered by body fluids and that virus is so extreme that even condoms can't stop it.

I have two questions

- Why saliva does not count (there are cases of humans and zombies kissing)?
- There are married couples where only one of them is a zombie and it seems unprobable that these couples don't do sex. So how come only one of them is a zombie?

Answer (score 2):

Logically a male zombie should not be able to have sex but since we are already ignoring that...

While there is no explanation in canon at the moment we can only assume that saliva contains a very, very small viral load requiring an actual bite and direct access to the blood stream to infect. It is also possible that zombie saliva contains an enzyme that inhibits the virus again making a massive infusion required for infection.

As to the only one pair of a married couple being a zombie, just because you're married doesn't mean you're having sex

Comment: Not just male zombies. :)

Comment: Why are we ignoring that? I am in the second season so information about condoms is not public knowledge.

Comment: Also is there only one confirmed married couple? I thought there were at least two to three confirmed and who knows how many unknown. I should rewatch some episodes probably.

Comment: "Just because your married doesnt mean your having sex" ---it's surprising how many times my first wife pops up on this site

Answer (score 1):

From the 2 questions you've mentioned in the question body, I can answer the second one.

*Q: There are married couples where only one of them is a zombie and it seems unprobable that these couples don't do sex. So how come only one of them is a zombie?*

**Spoilers :**

Answer:

> Many couples who match your criteria (zombie and human) were introduced later as the show progressed. Most suitable use case for this scenario is Detective Clive and Lt. Bozzio. Bozzio got infected with the Zombie virus after receiving the Aleutian flu vaccine that was tainted with Zombie blood. Clive did not get the vaccine because Liv managed to warn him just before he got his shot. After this, Bozzio became a zombie. There are multiple dialogues from the show where they discuss the strain this put into their sexual relationship and how they could no longer do it because that would turn Clive into a Zombie. Like Ravi found out, Zombie virus almost definitely transmits through even condoms.

> If you need another example, in season 4 episode 7, Chase Graves mentions that having sex with a human without disclosing the zombie status is a punishable crime, which solidifies Ravi's findings. *" Marsh was found guilty of turning a human into a zombie through sexual contact. She reported him for not disclosing his status. "*

So in a married couple, if only one of them is a zombie, it means the zombie got infected by someone else and the couple are definitely not having sex, however improbable it is.